# sql query to get termid in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Can any one please tell me the **sql query to get termid of a specific post in wordpress**.
I know the wordpress in build function to get this. But I need the raw Sql Query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE ...
```

This assumes a typical single-install of WordPress.    Multisite installs and installs where the table prefix was modified will have a different prefix to the posts table, the wp_ part.

What goes after the WHERE clause depends on HOW you are trying to fetch a post.

For example, if you know you want a post with the title "Select Me" you could use:

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%select me%';
```

LIKE is not required, of course.  That is a shortcut I use (which can be slow BTW) to avoid case issues or to select with a partial string.

You can find the database name and other info in the config files for WordPress.    If you are unsure of the table name use describe from a command line prompt or connect with a web based tool like phpMyAdmin.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple terms for the category so you can `join` the tables as below and provide the post id in the where clause

```
SELECT t.* FROM `wp_terms` t
INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` tt ON (t.`term_id` =tt.`term_id`)
LEFT JOIN `wp_term_relationships` ttr ON (tt.`term_taxonomy_id`= ttr.`term_taxonomy_id`)
LEFT JOIN `wp_posts` p ON (ttr.`object_id` = p.`ID`) WHERE p.`ID`=23 
// example post id is 23
```

In wp you can use [**Class Reference wpdb**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

```
global $wpdb;

$terms=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT t.* FROM $wpdb->prefix.`terms` t
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->prefix.`term_taxonomy` tt ON (t.`term_id` =tt.`term_id`)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->prefix.`term_relationships` ttr ON (tt.`term_taxonomy_id`= ttr.`term_taxonomy_id`)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->prefix.`posts` p ON (ttr.`object_id` = p.`ID`) WHERE p.`ID`=23 ");
```

As simple you can use WP's [**get_the_category()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) which will return the array of categories